# Getting value from localstorage back to it original state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a value I set in localStorage back to its original state. I saved `newLocation(40.7033127,-73.979681);` to the localStorage as `move1` and I am getting it with `localStorage.getItem("move1");`. As you can see it's a map coord so it should not be showing as `localStorage.getItem("move1")` it should automatically return the value of `move1`.

My question is how can I get the value instead of the code showing me `localStorage.getItem("move1");`?

Comment: can't understand your problem

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. `setItem()` and `getItem()` is all you need. What does `newLocation()` do? It would help to see a more complete sample of your code

Comment: Look like you are saving result of your function to localstorage, and possibly result of your function is object or undefined. When you put it into localstorage, it become "[object Object]" or "undefined" as a string. In case, if this is not a function call, but a string "newLocation(40.7033127,-73.979681);" you should get same sting.

Comment: If I understand right the `localStorage.getItem("move1")` return `newLocation(40.7033127,-73.979681)` and not the value of `newLocation()` function?

Comment: What does `newLocation(40.7033127,-73.979681);` return? Do you realize that localStorage stores strings, not objects?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct, it seems the problem exists because one always gets a String back from localStorage and you want to get it back in whatever type you saved it.

Then you should do: `localStorage.setItem("move1", JSON.stringify(sam)));`
And for the other one: `localStorage.setItem("move2", JSON.stringify(wise)));`

And then you could do:
 `new Location(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("move1")), JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("move2")));`

If that is what you want.

Comment: What exactly did not Work?

Comment: Maybee it would help, if you tell me which type newLocation() returns..

Comment: okay for example. I have this 
  var sam = 40.7033127;
  var wise = -73.979681;
i want i to show me
      newLocation(40.7033127,-73.979681);
instead of 
     newLocation(sam,wise);